# Extract filename from logfile using grep/awk

Tags: bash, awk

I want to find the name of the file from the logs. I tried it using `awk` command but could not succeed.

I tried :

```
FILE=`grep "^.java" /home/jimit/TestLogs.log | awk '{print $2}' | awk -F ':' '{print $1}'`
echo $FILE
```

Sample Logs: CommentService

```
Caused by: com.ofss.fc.framework.exception.BusinessException: The memo start date cannot be earlier than the process date.
    at com.ofss.fc.domain.party.service.core.CommentService.validateMemos(CommentService.java:474)
    at com.ofss.fc.domain.party.service.core.CommentService.addMemosToParty(CommentService.java:655)
```

Comment: In your example, the expected name of the file should look like  `CommentService.java` right?

Comment: Your very start is `grep "^.java"` which is looking for a line that starts with ".java". Obviously that's not going to match anything in your sample file.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$ grep -o "[^.(]*\.java" log  

CommentService.java                                                                                                   
CommentService.java
```